# JSP - What's the first step to serve JSP pages on my PC?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to start developing JSP pages. I need to set up a localhost on my PC at home.

What do I need to do to serve JSP pages locally?

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I am a ColdFusion developer and am running CF Builder as well as ColdFusion 9.

Here's the code I am trying to run saved as HelloWorld.jsp

```
<%
  java.util.Date dateToday = new java.util.Date();
%>

<html>
<body>
<p>Todays date is <%= dateToday %> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hover the JSP tag until a box pops up. Click therein the *info* link. At the bottom you can find some tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you need an Application server that interprets your JSP pages.
I would suggest you to use [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). It is in charge of receiving the requests from the client and return a result that is an HTML page. In other worlds apache transforms your JSP page (which is a mix of Java and HTML) in a pure HTML page. So the client doesn't need a virtual machine on it's side.

I would suggest you to use the eclipse web developments tools. They offer a good suite for programming and testing your page in eclipse.

[Here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html) you can find the instructions for installing tomcat. And [Here](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/#More-Info) some hints for configuring tomcat in eclipse.

If you already know Java it would be easy for you starting with JSP!

Comment: Thanks for your links. I am installing Eclipse right now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I you are a software developer Eclipse is what you need ;)

Comment: I have been developing ColdFusion application using CF Builder for about a year. In case you don't know, CF Builder is just Eclipse with the CF plugin (or something like that).

Comment: You should +1 this the answers that are useful ;)